# Create a batch file that compares a file name in a text file and a folder and if they match it will copy the file to another folder

Tags: batch-file, copy, compare

I have a text file that contains a file name (test.dll).

I want to check if this file (test.dll) exists in folder #1, and if YES, copy the file to another folder.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share with us what you've tried?

Comment: @ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "DEST_DIR=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Folder"
SET "SEARCH_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Toptix\4133R3_HF1\SRO 4000 Core\AppServer"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('type %~dp0list.txt') DO (
    FOR /R "%SEARCH_DIR%" %%f IN (*%%a*) DO (
        SET "SRC=%%~dpf"
        SET DEST=!SRC:%SEARCH_DIR%=%DEST_DIR%!
        xcopy /S /I "%%~f" "!DEST!"
    )
)

Comment: @RonOvadia: I have just tested your batch script and it works correcty. Sincerely, I am not able to uderstand where is the lack; please let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your batch script works correctly but it seems quite redundant. Just clean it, as in the following quotation:

> @ECHO OFF
>   SET "DEST_DIR=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\[folder_1]"
>   SET "SEARCH_DIR=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\[folder_2]"
>   FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('type [your_list].txt') DO (
>   FOR /R "%SEARCH_DIR%" %%f IN (%%a) DO (xcopy /S /I "%%~f" "%DEST_DIR%" 2> NUL)
>   )

I have added the `2> NUL` statement that redirects to nothing the `STDERR` output. Consider by yourself whether to hold it or not.